# How to define a loop that can get the data based on a number in MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, loops, oop, content-management-system

I'm developing a cms with PHP OOP and in this project I wanted to add a page where admins of a site can simply see all the menu navigation of website and browse them and edit the menu links.

In MySQL database I have created a table called `menu_nav` and in this table I have created 16 columns and admins can make menus with up to menu links:

[print screen of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZREjV.png)

And for example I have inserted a menu called `top_nav` and it has 5 menu items.

Now in order to retrieve this data into a page where admins can edit menu links, I did this:

```
<div class='box-body table-responsive no-padding'>
                      <table class='table table-hover'>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Number</th>
                          <th>Link</th>
                          <th></th>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                          <td>1</td>
                          <td>".$menuSet->GetMenuLink1($id)."</td>
                          <td>
                            <a title='Edit' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>
                            <a title='Remove' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a>
                            <a title='Move Down' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'></span></a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>2</td>
                          <td>".$menuSet->GetMenuLink2($id)."</td>
                          <td>
                            <a title='Edit' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>
                            <a title='Remove' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a>
                            <a title='Move Up' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up'></span></a>
                            <a title='Move Down' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'></span></a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>3</td>
                          <td>".$menuSet->GetMenuLink3($id)."</td>
                          <td>
                            <a title='Edit' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>
                            <a title='Remove' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a>
                            <a title='Move Up' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up'></span></a>
                            <a title='Move Down' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'></span></a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>4</td>
                          <td>".$menuSet->GetMenuLink4($id)."</td>
                          <td>
                            <a title='Edit' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>
                            <a title='Remove' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a>
                            <a title='Move Up' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up'></span></a>
                            <a title='Move Down' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'></span></a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>5</td>
                          <td>".$menuSet->GetMenuLink5($id)."</td>
                          <td>
                            <a title='Edit' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>
                            <a title='Remove' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a>
                            <a title='Move Up' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up'></span></a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </div>
```

And the result is this:

[print screen of menu settings page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqe6X.png)

But what I wanted to do is to count the `menu_items` field in table and make the table upon that number. For example if it is set to 5, then it should dynamically make a table with 5 rows and get the data from each column in table via a loop till the `menu_link_5` and it finishes the loop.

So because the theory behind this is very complicated to me, I need some help from some experts in programming. So I just found out this forum and I hope someone can help me with that cause I really need it !

And also here is the `menu.class.php` if you want to take a look at it:

```
<?php 
class Menus
{
    public $id,$mname,$menui,$menul1,$menul2,$menul3,$menul4,$menul5,$menul6,$menul7,$menul8,$menul9,$menul10,$menul11,$menul12,$menul13;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new Connection();
        $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();
    }
    public function GetMenus()
    {
        if(empty($name))
        {
            $menu = $this->db->prepare("select * from menu_nav");
            $menu->execute();
            $menu_array = array();
            while($row = $menu->fetch())
            {
                $menu_array[] = $row;
            }
            return $menu_array;
        }
        else
        {
            header("Location: php/includes/errors/008.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
    public function SelectMenuById($id)
    {
        if(!empty($id))
        {
            $mnu = $this->db->prepare("select * from menu_nav where id = ?");
            $mnu->bindParam(1,$id);
            $mnu->execute();
            while($row = $mnu->fetch())
            {
                $this->id           = $row['id'];
                $this->mname        = $row['menu_name'];
                $this->menui        = $row['menu_items'];
                $this->menul1       = $row['menu_link_1'];
                $this->menul2       = $row['menu_link_2'];
                $this->menul3       = $row['menu_link_3'];
                $this->menul4       = $row['menu_link_4'];
                $this->menul5       = $row['menu_link_5'];
                $this->menul6       = $row['menu_link_6'];
                $this->menul7       = $row['menu_link_7'];
                $this->menul8       = $row['menu_link_8'];
                $this->menul9       = $row['menu_link_9'];
                $this->menul10      = $row['menu_link_10'];
                $this->menul11      = $row['menu_link_11'];
                $this->menul12      = $row['menu_link_12'];
                $this->menul13      = $row['menu_link_13'];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            header("Location: php/includes/errors/009.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
    public function DeleteMenu($id)
    {
        if(!empty($id))
        {
            $adm = $this->db->prepare("delete from menu_nav where id = ?");
            $adm->bindParam(1,$id);
            $adm->execute();
        }
        else
        {
            header("Location: php/includes/errors/010.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
    public function GetId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function GetMenuName()
    {
        return $this->mname;
    }
    public function GetMenuItems()
    {
        return $this->menui;
    }
    public function GetMenuLink1()
    {
        return $this->menul1;
    }
    public function GetMenuLink2()
    {
        return $this->menul2;
    }
    public function GetMenuLink3()
    {
        return $this->menul3;
    }
    public function GetMenuLink4()
    {
        return $this->menul4;
    }
    public function GetMenuLink5()
    {
        return $this->menul5;
    }
    public function GetMenuLink6()
    {
        return $this->menul6;
    }
    public function GetMenuLink7()
    {
        return $this->menul7;
    }
    public function GetMenuLink8()
    {
        return $this->menul8;
    }
    public function GetMenuLink9()
    {
        return $this->menul9;
    }
    public function GetMenuLink10()
    {
        return $this->menul10;
    }
    public function GetMenuLink11()
    {
        return $this->menul11;
    }
    public function GetMenuLink12()
    {
        return $this->menul12;
    }
    public function GetMenuLink13()
    {
        return $this->menul13;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would argue that your database structure isn't optimal. You shouldn't really have empty columns in this scenario, as it just complicates things. I'd recommend that you normalize the data to help with the data redundancy <sup>[read more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)</sup>.

[image]

This eliminates the need for the empty columns. Now that we have dealt with your database structure, this obviously means changes to your code. With this, it also means that you can have unlimited menu items without adding columns to your database.

In your `SelectMenuById()` function, we are going to split the queries, to get the menu name we will just do the following

```
SELECT name FROM menu WHERE id = ?
```

The query to get the menu links we will do the following:

```
SELECT menu_items.id,
       menu_items.link 
FROM   menu, 
       menu_items 
WHERE  menu.id = ?
   AND menu_items.menu_id = menu.id
```

Result (with ID 1):

[image]

<sup>[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cdfa60/1)</sup>

Next, we get rid of all of your `$menul1`, `$menul2` etc. variables and replace them with a `$menuItems` variable (or something along those lines). Back to your `SelectMenuById()` function, it now looks something like this <sup>untested</sup>:

```
public function SelectMenuById($id)
{
    if(!empty($id))
    {
        $mnu = $this->db->prepare("select * from menu where id = ?");
        $mnu->bindParam(1,$id);
        $mnu->execute();
        $result = $mnu->fetch();

        $this->id = $result['id'];
        $this->mname = $result['name'];

        $mnu = $this->db->prepare("SELECT menu_items.id, menu_items.link FROM menu, menu_items WHERE  menu.id = ? AND menu_items.menu_id = menu.id;");
        $mnu->bindParam(1,$id);
        $mnu->execute();

        while($row = $mnu->fetch())
        {
            $this->menuItems[] = ["id" => $row['id'], "link" => $row['link']];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location: php/includes/errors/009.php");
        exit();
    }
}
```

You should add a getter method for `$this->menuItems` and remove the getters for the other variables. And finally, to your HTML. We just use a `foreach()` loop to get the results on the page <sup>untested</sup>.

```
<div class='box-body table-responsive no-padding'>
  <table class='table table-hover'>
    <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Link</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        foreach($menuSet->getMenuItems() as $menuItemID => $menuItem):
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $menuItemID; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $menuItem; ?></td>
      <td>
        <a title='Edit' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>
        <a title='Remove' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a>
        <a title='Move Down' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'></span></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        endforeach;
    ?>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer but it returns this error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() !

Comment: Did you create a `getMenuItems()` function that returns `$this->menuItems` in `menu.class.php`?

Comment: Yes I did, you can see the edited class [here](http://www.paste.org/85151)

Comment: does `$this->menuItems` get populated?

Comment: And in the html I set it like this: `foreach($menuSet->GetMenuItems() as $menuItemID => $menuItem):`

Comment: Try doing `print_r($this->menuItems);` after the while loop on line 48

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found it by this way:

```
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){ 
                            $func = "GetMenuLink".$i;
                            echo "
                                <tr>
                                <td>$i</td>
                                <td>".$menuSet->$func()."</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a title='Edit' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>&nbsp; 
                                    <a title='Remove' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                            ";
                            // replace $menuSet->GetMenuLink1() with another variable
                        }
```